# Why receiving shifted and duplicated data in SPI communication between Raspberry Pi (master) and Nucleo l432kc boards (slaves)

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, stm32, spi, mbed

​I've asked the same question on the ST Q&A forum and on the Raspberry Pi forum, but I didn't receive any answer. I hope that here there is someone that can help me.

I want to make communicate two Nucleo l432kc (slaves) with a Raspberry Pi (master) through the SPI protocol. On the Raspberry I'm using the Spidev API, while on the Nucleo I'm using the HAL SPI interface with DMA.

The only configuration that permits a stable transmission is the SPI_MODE_2 of Spidev that corresponds to the SPI_POLARITY_HIGH and SPI_PHASE_2EDGE configuration of the HAL.

With the above configuration I have two problems:

1. The messages sent by the master to the slaves arrive always correctly, but all the messages sent by the slaves to the master always arrive shifted by 1 bit on the right (e.g. if I send two bytes `0b00000011 0b00000001` I receive `0b00000001 0b10000000`). It seems that the sampling of the MISO signal is delayed but I can't figure out why.
2. I receive the data on both the slaves regardless if the chip select is set or not. In the response of the slaves I have no collisions so I think that only the MISO bus is effectively set in high impedance mode in the slave when the NSS is high.

To test purpose I've tried to use the SPISlave class of the mbed framework,
this class cannot use the DMA so I can't use it in the real program. Using it I solve the first problem but the second persists.

Another thing that could be useful is that with the SPISlave class I can use all the 4 mode of the SPI protocol, of course the slaves and the master must use the same mode but is not import which one. 
As I said before with the HAL interface I can use only the SPI_MODE_2.

This is the configuration code that runs on both the slaves:

```
// SPI
__HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();

/* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
hspi.Instance = SPI1; 
hspi.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
hspi.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;   // full duplex mode 
hspi.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;       // dimension of 1 byte
hspi.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;    // start and idle clk value
hspi.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;         // edge of sampling of data both on miso and mosi        
hspi.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;        // bit order
hspi.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;        // disabling the TI mode
hspi.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE; // disable crc calc
hspi.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;           // disable NSS puls value

if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi) != HAL_OK)
  return false;

  /* SPI1 interrupt Init */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);

// GPIO 
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
/**SPI1 GPIO Configuration    
PA1     ------> SPI1_SCK
PA11     ------> SPI1_MISO
PA12     ------> SPI1_MOSI 
PB0     ------> SPI1_NSS 
*/
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);


// DMA 
/* DMA controller clock enable */
__HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* SPI1 DMA Init */
/* SPI1_RX Init */
hdma_spi_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_1;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_spi_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;

if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi_rx) != HAL_OK) return false;

 __HAL_LINKDMA(&hspi,hdmarx,hdma_spi_rx);
/* DMA interrupt init */
/* DMA1_Channel2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);

/* SPI1 DMA Init */
/* SPI1_TX Init */
hdma_spi_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_1;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_spi_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;

if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi_tx) != HAL_OK) return false;

__HAL_LINKDMA(&hspi,hdmatx,hdma_spi_tx);

/* DMA interrupt init */
/* DMA1_Channel3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
```

And this is the code that runs on the master:

```
unsigned int bitsPerByte = 8u;
unsigned int delay =  0u; 
unsigned int speed = 100; // hz
unsigned int cs_change   = 0u;  // false in C

// initialization
fd = ::open("/dev/spidev0.0", O_RDWR);
auto mode = SPI_MODE_2;  // clock polarity low, clock phase second edge

if (fd == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't open the spi device");

if (::ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode) == -1) 
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't set the spi mode"); 

 /*
 * bits per word
 */
auto bits = bitsPerByte;
auto ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
if (ret == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can't set bits per word");

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
if (ret == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can't get bits per word");

/*
 * max speed hz
 */
auto maxSpeed = speed;
ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &maxSpeed);
if (ret == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can't set max speed hz");

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &maxSpeed);
if (ret == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can't get max speed hz");

// code used for sending messages
void transfer(uint8_t *tx, uint8_t *rx, size_t size) {
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {  
        (unsigned long)tx,  // .tx_buf 
        (unsigned long)rx,  // .rx_buf        
        size,               // .len  
        speed,              // .speed_hz
        delay,              // .delay_usecs
        bitsPerByte,        // .bits_per_word
        cs_change,          // .cs_change
        0,                  // .tx_nbits
        0,                  // .rx_nbits
        0,                  // .pad
    };

    if (::ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr) == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't send data throught the spi");
}
```

In the main functions of the slaves the only thing that I actually do is to send back the exact packet that I receive.

### EDIT

On the forum of the Raspberry someone told me to use piscope to see the digital value that is send on the pins. I've done it and I've seen that the CE0 and CE1 pin are always low. I can't understand why I do not have collisions on the MISO.

### EDIT 2

I've solved the second problem (the duplicated data) it was an error on the master configuration, I was using `cs_change = 1` but it must be equal to 0.

With [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) I've figured out that the slaves are sending the data correctly, it's the master that does not read them well.

Comment: The off by one is typical for a wrong clock edge or the idle state of SCK is different between active and inactive SPI (which would create a clock tick if you activate SPI. You need to use pull-up/-down resistors for SCK).

Comment: all right, I should use the pull-down on the slaves or on the master?

Comment: The usual way would be close to the master and if you have pull-downs for the other lines also (which is a good idea) put them somewhere together. But it doesn't really matter. You only want to have a defined value. You can even place them at both ends if you like to.

Comment: I've tried with both pull up and pull down (first pull up and then pull down), nothing change.